# Field "customerCode" required when sending FormData with MultipartFile

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm trying to send multiform data. But I'm getting an error: Field "customerCode" required when sending FormData with MultipartFile
Even I am adding customerCode to the form.
(In the last 2-3 projects i used same code but i did not get error)
Yes, I have checked similar question but it did not work for me.

```
  Future<CommonApiResponseModel> sellItem(String token, String customerCode, String categoryCode, String price, String title, String description, List<String> imageList) async {
    final form = FormData({});
    var headerMap = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    };
    for(String path in imageList){
      form.files.add(MapEntry("adsImages[]", MultipartFile(File(path), filename: "${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.${path.split(".").last}")));
      }
    print(customerCode);
    form.fields.add(MapEntry('customerCode', customerCode));
    form.fields.add(MapEntry('categoryCode', categoryCode));
    form.fields.add(MapEntry('price', price));
    form.fields.add(MapEntry('title', title));
    form.fields.add(MapEntry('description', description));

    // print(form.fields);
    final response = await post("${ApiService.BASE_URL}/addAds", form, headers: headerMap);
    print("Image upload response: $response");

    }
  }
```